# Like query in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

```
NSString * strSearchSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT pdf_id,pdf_name,page_no,pdf_image,pdf_text FROM search WHERE pdf_text LIKE '\%%@\%'",strSearchString];
```

In This Query i got the String like
given below

```
SELECT pdf_id,pdf_name,page_no,pdf_image,pdf_text FROM search WHERE pdf_text LIKE '%@'
```

I want like this

```
SELECT pdf_id,pdf_name,page_no,pdf_image,pdf_text FROM search WHERE pdf_text LIKE '%searchtext%'
```

Please give me hint or provide me a document.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Escape the `%` symbols in your query like this `%%` instead of `\%`.

```
NSString *strSearchSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT pdf_id,pdf_name,page_no,pdf_image,pdf_text FROM search WHERE pdf_text LIKE '%%%@%%'", strSearchString];
```